# iOS Mapkit Getting Point From Overlaid View

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, mapkit, latitude-longitude

I am implementing a location picking view where I would like the pin to stay centered on the map, so that as the user pans the map left/right, the pin stays centered.  To do this, I have added a subview UIImageView for the pin at the center of the map.

When the user selects the location, I have tried to retrieve the coordinate by one of these two methods:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [self.mapView convertPoint:self.pinImageView.center toCoordinateFromView:self.pinImageView];

MKCoordinateRegion myRegion = [self.mapView convertRect:self.pinImageView.frame  toRegionFromView:self.mapView];
```

This works perfectly, except I notice that when the user has the map zoomed at different levels, I have different sized **discrepancies** when re-using these points only in the **vertical/latitude axis**.

On ViewWillAppear, I have tried re-centering the map using both the point and converting it to a region or passing the region itself.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

if([self.priorLatitude length] >0)
    {

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D priorCoordinate;
        float priorLatitudeFloat = [self.priorLatitude floatValue];
        float priorLongitudeFloat = [self.priorLongitude floatValue];

        priorCoordinate.latitude = priorLatitudeFloat;
        priorCoordinate.longitude = priorLongitudeFloat;

        //MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(priorCoordinate, 800, 800);
        //[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

        [self.mapView setRegion:self.myRegion animated:YES];


    }
```

}

Here for example is the log of repeating setLocation without moving the map at all and the change in the y axis.

```
Printing description of self->_myRegion:
(MKCoordinateRegion) _myRegion = {
  center = (latitude = 43.76**9625**114267697, longitude = -79.261707572949575)
  span = (latitudeDelta = 0.00011621367119118986, longitudeDelta = 0.00017166140757751691)
}

(MKCoordinateRegion) _myRegion = {
  center = (latitude = 43.76**9454**667211292, longitude = -79.261707572949547)
  span = (latitudeDelta = 0.000116214002375159, longitudeDelta = 0.00017166140757751691)
}
```

Comment: If the imageView of your pin is centered over the map you can just call `mapView.centerCoordinate` to get the coordinate. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I will try this and see if I have better luck, thank you.

Comment: did it work for what you needed?